# Custom painting Windows Forms Scrollbar?

Tags: winforms, scrollbar, skinning

I know how to do custom drawing of a standalone Windows Forms ScrollBar because there are plenty of examples at places like codeproject.com. But how do you custom draw the scrollbars in controls you do not create yourself? For example a Panel can show scrollbars but how would I ensure that the scrollbars it shows are custom drawn?

Or maybe this is not possible and I would need to create my own version of a Panel so that they use my own custom drawing scrollbars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrollbars you see most often, including those built into most winforms controls, are rendered by Windows and there is no way to override their appearance in WinForms short of implementing an entirely custom solution which completely takes over the rendering and behavior of the common scrollbar control.  There are some commercial packagages which claim to do this (google winforms skinning).